# create a dynamic menu with some mega-menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i tried to create a dynamic menu, each one contain a block like the one in image, i tried the next jquery codes but it didn't work

Here is an example of the menu i want to create

[image]

```js
 $(".drop-down").click(function() {
      $('.mega-menu').addClass('display-on');
                        $('.mega-menu').siblings().removeClass('dislplay-on');
     });
     
});
```

```css
.drop-down > a:after{
            content:"\f103";
            color:#fff;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            font-style: normal;
            margin-left: 5px;
}
nav.menu{min-height: 45px;
      background: coral;  
     display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
.menu > ul > li{list-style: none;
            display:inline-block;
            color:#fff;
            line-height: 45px
}
.mega-menu{position: absolute;
           background: none repeat scroll #888;
            width:100%;
            margin-top: 3px;
            padding:15px;
            left:0;
            display: none;
            transition-duration: 0.9s
}
.display-on{
                display:block;
             transition-duration: 0.9s;
}
.mega-menu ul{margin: 0 25px}
```

```html
<!-- Here is the html content-->

<nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="drop-down">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="mega-menu fadeIn animated">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="drop-down">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="mega-menu fadeIn animated">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="drop-down">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="mega-menu fadeIn animated">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <ul>
                          <li>gaagag</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                          <li>test</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this image, when u click in main lists above, a new block slidedown and the previous one disappear, i want to create one like this:

[image]

Comment: So, just a quick glace at your logic, which single mega-menu are you trying to show?  And reading the logic you have, how would that target the desired mega-menu?  I'm pretty sure I know what you're after, but I want you to think about what you want, and what your logic is currently written to do.

Comment: i want to make the design look like this, when i click on a drop-down, active its direct child (mega-menu), and when i click on another parent (drop-down) ,disable the previous and active its child

Comment: Right, but like I asked, read your logic.  How is that logic going to target the specific mega-menu you want?  I'm asking you to understand what the logic you have written is actually doing.  Once you understand that, then you will either know what you need to do, or will have a better idea of the "How do i ....." question you should be asking instead.

Comment: Exactly this is my point, how do i ?!, i know what i want to accomplish, the method is just the obstacle right now

Comment: 'this' inside the click handler will be the dropdown that was clicked.  each dropdown has a child mega-menu you want to show.  `$('.mega-menu')` selects all mega-menu, not just the one in the dropdown clicked.  `$('.mega-menu', this)` will return you only the mega-menu inside the dropdown menu clicked.

Comment: My point of asking you to read your code was to verify you understood what `$('.mega-menu')` does.

Comment: you completely right!, all the others ('.mega-menu') get the same class, i have tried $('.mega-menu', this) but same thing happened, all mega-menu get the class

Comment: I'd have to ask you to show the issue using the `$('.mega-menu', this)` version because that should definitely not put the class on all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there was some mix-up with what was being clicked and how it related to your drop-down and link.  I came up with this which appears to work.

```js
$(".drop-down > a").click(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this).closest('.drop-down');
  $('.mega-menu').removeClass('display-on');
  $dropdown.find('.mega-menu').addClass('display-on');
});
```

```css
.drop-down>a:after {
  content: "\f103";
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

nav.menu {
  min-height: 45px;
  background: coral;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.menu>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 45px
}

.mega-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: none repeat scroll #888;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  transition-duration: 0.9s
}

.display-on {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
}

.mega-menu ul {
  margin: 0 25px
}
```

```html
<!-- Here is the html content-->

<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="drop-down">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <div class="mega-menu fadeIn animated">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <div class="mega-menu fadeIn animated">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <div class="mega-menu fadeIn animated">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>gaagag</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am so sorry, i didnt try your jquery Code , i am sorry again, and Thank you so much, you successfully solved my issue